# Find the largest number that is lesser than a given number in a sorted list

Tags: scala, list

Suppose I need to find the largest number lesser than given number `y` in a sorted list.
For instance

```
def findLargest(xs: List[Int], y: Int): Option[Int] = ???

val xs = List(1, 2, 4, 8)
findLargest(xs, 5) // should return Some(4)
findLargest(xs, 1) // None
findLargest(xs, 9) // Some(8)
```

How would you implement this function ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems have you ran into, when implementing this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def findLargest(xs: List[Int], y: Int): Option[Int] = {
    xs.takeWhile(_ < y).lastOption
}
```

Comment: This will not give the correct output if the list is not sorted as `val xs = List(1, 2, 7, 4, 8)`

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, the question is clear the list is sorted

Answer (score 2):

you can define as

```
   def findLargest(xs: List[Int], y: Int): Option[Int] = xs.filter(x => x < y).sorted.lastOption
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the list is sorted:

```
def findLargest(xs: List[Int], y: Int): Option[Int] = xs.reverse.find(_ < y)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using Collect**

Assuming the list is sorted in ascending order

```
def findLargest(xs: List[Int], y: Int): Option[Int] = 
  xs.reverse.collect { case x if x < y => x }.headOption
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> def findLargest(xs: List[Int], y: Int): Option[Int] =
     |       xs.reverse.collect { case x if x < y => x }.headOption
findLargest: (xs: List[Int], y: Int)Option[Int]

scala> findLargest(List(1, 2,  3), 1)
res3: Option[Int] = None

scala> findLargest(List(1, 2,  3), 2)
res4: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> findLargest(List(1, 2,  3), 3)
res5: Option[Int] = Some(2)
```